# Kali Linux || Mac Book Pro 16" || German Keyboard || Can't get option/command key to work properly

Tags: kali-linux, keyboard, macos

I just set up Kali Linux in a Virtual Box on my MacBook Pro 16".
I was trying to use the terminal (i.e. Terminal Emulator) but encountered problems. I.e. I was not able to for example get the `pipe (|)` or `tilde (~)` character to work.
Also, copy-pasting in the terminal via `command+c` / `command+v` does not work. Typically, I would get the pipe character via `option + 7`.
But here, when I push `option+7` nothing happens immediately. However, the next character I type is repeated 7 times. No idea what's happening there.

This seems to be confirmed by running `xmodmap -pke` in kali, as can be seen below:
[image]

My keyboard settings are as follows:
[image]

My locales (`locales`) are as follows (I also tried German also, but that did not change anything):

[image]

`mousepad /etc/default/keyboard` yields:

[image]

running `xev` and then hitting my left `option-key` results in the following events (which looks good to me?):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Settings (Einstellungen) - Region: Add German as Language when necessary and for Keyboard add German macintosh and of course choose it afterwards ;)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIDqRZ6KWWc

Comment: That doesn't quite do it. I got the german keyboard working and can use Umlaute for example. However, the option and command key do not work as supposed. Might also have to do with the fact that kali is running in a virtual box

Comment: Nur um sicher zu gehen: German MACINTOSH Keyboard?

Comment: yes! 16” with touchbar.